# Why are the spheres moving with the gem?

Tags: modeling

So i am trying to make a crown and im trying to add in this gem made from a cylinder[image: Cylindrical gem]

and Im trying to move it the outside of the crown I'm making that has UV spheres on it as gems as well, but no matter what i do it always moves them along with the gem[image: Gem in center of crown, spheres on outside][image: Gem moved along Y axis, moving spheres outwards with it]

Comment: It would help to see the actual blend file, but it looks like you have some kind of parenting relationship between the gem and the spheres.

Comment: You should move the mesh in edit mode rather than object mode

Comment: I think you could share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ This could be a variety of things (Proportional Editing springs to mind?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my haste to figure out the crown i didn't realize that proportional editing was on, I am fairly new so wooo, but that was the issue thank you to those who helped in the comments

Comment: Hi, Dark Eye .. Glad it's a fix. :)  When a 'cooling off' period has passed, you can come back and accept your self-answer, with the tick at the side. That would mark your question solved, and tidy everything up.